# Is this a valid way to include an observer pattern?

Tags: c++, class

To get away from global variables I decided to take a look at the observer-pattern. I wanted to implement it in the least complicated way.

The problem I wanted to solve is this:

I have a window class that handles resizing of the main window.
If the window resizes I have different classes that need to be informed when that happens.
So i wrote a little Observer interface:

```
#pragma once
class IObserverWindow{
public:
   virtual void onResizing(int width, int height) = 0;
};
```

I added this interface to my cursor class.

Now to get the clients (cursor class) registered by the window class I implemented a vector and a function:

```
#include "IObserverWindow.h"
...
public:
   void registerClient(IObserverWindow* client);
...
private:
   std::vector<IObserverWindow*> list;
```

In my main class I invoke both classes and register the cursor class:

```
bwindow = new BioWindow();
bwindow->init("TestWindow", 1200, 800);
bwindow->showOSCursor(true);

bcursor = new Cursor();
bcursor->setIcon("cursor.png");
bwindow->registerClient((IObserverWindow*)bcursor);
```

FYI: the cursor class inherits the `IObserverWindow`, the window class just includes the `IObserverWindow`.

As the window class does know nothing about the cursor class I had to cast the cursor class to an `IObserverWindow` interface (as defined in the register function).

This works without complains from the compiler and it works without problems when the program is running, but...

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.
Should I create a parent class to register with my vector, so that all observer classes (like the cursor class) are a child from this parent?

Or is it actualy a valid way to cast the cursor class down to its interface?

Comment: You might find interest in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592847/c11-observer-pattern-signals-slots-events-change-broadcaster-listener-or).

Comment: Have you implemented `onResizing` in the `BioWindow` class?

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Yeah, everything is working as expected. I just wasnt shure if this is correct.